# Regular Expression for Matching Legal Identifier Names

Tags: regex, jflex

I'm kinda a newbie to this regular expression thing. I am trying to write a regular expression to match an identifier that follows these rules:

It must begin with a letter and can have only letters, digits and underscores. The identifier must also end with a letter and must not have two consecutive underscores.

I've tried to come up with the regex for this but I haven't had much success. I need help.

Comment: please share what you tried and why it doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

Use regex pattern

```
\b[a-zA-Z](?:[a-zA-Z\d]|(?<!_)_(?!_))*[a-zA-Z]\b
```

If you want to add also minimum and maximum length (for example min. 6 and max. 12), then use

```
\b(?=\w{6,12}\b)[a-zA-Z](?:[a-zA-Z\d]|(?<!_)_(?!_))*[a-zA-Z]\b
```

Comment: @user1691402 - If you want to verify if input contains **ONLY** such "legal identifier name", then use regex pattern `^[a-zA-Z](?:[a-zA-Z\d]|(?<!_)_(?!_))*[a-zA-Z]$` for no size limitation identifier names and regex pattern `^(?=\w{6,12}$)[a-zA-Z](?:[a-zA-Z\d]|(?<!_)_(?!_))*[a-zA-Z]$` for min/max limitation names.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a sample that I could do**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(test("a"));
    System.out.println(test("a_a"));
    System.out.println(test("a2_f"));
    System.out.println(test("a_2f"));
    System.out.println(test("a2_fasd"));
    System.out.println(test("dsads_dsadsa"));
    System.out.println(test("d_sads_dsads_a"));
    System.out.println(test("a2_3241_4324_2f"));
    //fails
    System.out.println(test("2_3241_4324_2f"));
    System.out.println(test("a2_3241__4324_2f"));
    System.out.println(test("_dsads_dsadsa"));
    System.out.println(test("dsads_dsadsa_"));
}

//validation
public static boolean test(String name) {
    String regEx = "^[a-zA-Z](_?[a-zA-Z0-9]+)*_?[a-zA-Z]$||^[a-zA-Z]([a-zA-Z0-9]+_?)*[a-zA-Z]$||^[a-zA-Z]_[a-zA-Z]$||^[a-zA-Z]$";
    return Pattern.matches(regEx, name);
}

------------------------
Printed results
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
true
false
false
false
false
```